# Suggestions to fix columns in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make 3 columns be dead centered?
They are spread out currently.

```
<div class="container container2">
 <div class="row no-gutter">
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <h1>1</h1>
     <p class="description1">elige<br>tu box</p>
      <img class="crop-img" src="img/icono_elige.jpg" alt="delivery" />
     <p class="description">elije entre la</br><b>box mensual</b> o la <b> </br>    box personalizada</b></p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
     <h1>2</h1>
      <p class="description1">elige<br>tus snacks</p>
       <img class="crop-img" src="img/icono_snacks.jpg" alt="elige" />
        <p class="description">encuentra mas de<br> <b>80 snacks</b> y<br>agregalos a tu box</p>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h1>3</h1>
        <p class="description1">pide y<br>recibe</p>
         <img class="crop-img" src="img/icono_delivery.png" alt=elige />
                    <p class="description">para ti, para<br> compartir o para<br>regalar</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyprr.jpg

Top - What I have

Bottom - What I need

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three boxes have the same width (some where around 33.3333%). I think you're using `text-align: center;` which will place the contents in the middle of the boxes. I think the best solution is making the middle box smaller.

You can also use `col-push` and `col-pull`.

To find more information about this, check http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting.

Just try using different sizes of columns and offsetting these.

Comment: @Velix007 You can mark my answer as right, if you want :)